# Para fazer uma otimização extrema, x < 11 é mais eficiente que x <= 10?

Tags: desempenho, característica-linguagem, operadores

É mais rápido usar o *operador de menor* (`<`) do que o *operador de menor ou igual* (`<=`) em um `if` quando dá o mesmo resultado nas linguagens de programação? Qual tem menor custo de processamento se precisar de otimização extrema dessas operações com inteiros? Elas geram o mesmo código de máquina?

Então qual o mais eficiente?

```
if (x < 10)
```

ou

```
if (x <= 11)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nem vou falar que depende da linguagem porque é mais que isso, depende da implementação. E pode mudar em cada versão, nada obriga ser de um jeito ou outro. Pode mudar até dependendo de onde vai rodar, porque é comum que isso seja delegado para o processador e nem depende da linguagem que está usando, a não ser que ela escolheu delegar.

De qualquer forma, mesmo que tenha alguma diferença deve usar o que é mais legível para o caso. E mesmo que tenha não pode ser muito diferente.

E a maioria dos compiladores, em linguagens que prezam pela performance e eficiência, fariam uma otimização se houvesse diferença.

Se tiver alguma, é "culpa" do processador que executa de forma diferente. Mas é improvável que aconteça em arquiteturas modernas. Há mais relatos de ter diferença no passado.

E pode nem depender só da expressão simples, pode envolver algo mais que pode mudar o resultado.

No processador, essa expressão costuma ser executada em duas partes, uma que testa a condição e outra que decide para onde ir, ou seja, é a segunda instrução que escolhe efetivamente o que fazer.

Eu fui buscar casos assim e achei uma [resposta muito bem votada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135533/221800) que mostra que cada compilador usa uma instrução diferente e que o custo de execução de cada uma é o mesmo seguindo o manual da Intel (pode ser diferente em outros processadores). Tem [casos mostrados lá que são diferentes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135550/221800), mas indica igual, dá na mesma.

Eu fiz um teste em algumas implementações disponíveis no Compiler Explorer (não vou testar todas as linguagens possíveis).

De cara vi que [o GCC fez uma otimização para gerar o mesmo código](https://godbolt.org/z/PevG3Tz9P). [Com ARM deu na mesma](https://godbolt.org/z/qabssf5ss). Diferente do que o rapaz achou lá com o mesmo compilador em outra versão.

O [MSVC de fato usa instruções diferentes](https://godbolt.org/z/Yboqv4jTn). [No ARM também](https://godbolt.org/z/Px78PMG6e).

O [Clang segue o mesmo caminho](https://godbolt.org/z/ba61P94j8). [Idem para o ICC](https://godbolt.org/z/s5fjn5Gnj).

Testei com C e C++, confie em mim, deu na mesma.

[Para C# também foi assim](https://godbolt.org/z/6T4qsbbde).

Rodando em [linguagem sobre VM vai pelo mesmo caminho](https://godbolt.org/z/Kr9W1a9c4). Precisaria ver como funciona a VM, mas em tese as duas instruções de comparação devem dar mesmo resultado de desempenho. Se não der, é Python, não importa.

Se quiser, teste nas outras linguagens disponíveis ou em algumas que não tem lá.

Pode acontecer diferente se o teste for um pouco diferente. Não testei se só tiver variáveis e nada de literal ou constante (já vi casos em outras questões que só a magnitude do literal mudando já mudava a otimização). Não testei se a condição for composta, pode dar algo diferente. Não testei com algum literal mais específico, pode ser que com o `< 2` por exemplo tenha alguma otimização extra para alguma implementação, mas se usar `<= 3` não faça a otimização, a não ser com o GCC atual que pode fazer primeiro uma otimização e depois abre a porta para a outra. Otimização é algo bem complicado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Veja pl-sql por exemplo , o Oracle faz a conversão automática do tipo , x pode ser 10.5 ( notação USA) o que mudaria o comportamento da coisa , depende como diz o @Maniero . Não sendo uma aplicação que exija uma performance muito alta eu prefiro no código "pecar" pela clareza.

Comment: Nem entrei no mérito de SQL porque aí cai em outro nível. A questão da clareza nem é tão importante neste caso, mas ajuda vc fazer de acordo com o real problema ser inclusivo ou não, não tem que converter mentalmente o real para o código.

Comment: Eu digo a questão da clareza na questão de pesar entre a otimização e a clareza , se estou fazendo uma simulação de clima que precisa fazer cálculos de alta escala é uma coisa pois cada nanossegundo conta , se é um sistema contábil outra, o famoso DEPENDE.